# Single Responsibility Principle : Proxy Pattern for refactoring

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented, refactoring, single-responsibility, proxy

> However, in cases where the tests did not force the separation, and the smells of Rigidity and Fragility become strong, the design should be refactored using
> the Facade or Proxy patterns to separate the two responsibilities.

From : [Agile Software Development: Principles, Patterns, and Practices](https://books.google.com.pr/books/about/Agile_Software_Development.html?id=0HYhAQAAIAAJ&hl=es-419)

I understand how Facade can be used. I am not able to get how proxy would be helpful.

Can someone provide and example of how Proxy Pattern can be used for refactoring here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Given the example where you want to *unit* test some code that does CORBA or other remote call.

During the test phase you don't have the proper environment online. Refactoring this concern and creating a proper testable code can be achieved with a **Proxy** pattern, where your concrete proxy implementation would delegate the calls to another concrete class. That enables the separation of concerns quoted on your question.

[image: UML of a PROXY Pattern]

Then during a *integration* test you can actually test the remote behaviour.